# Movie API:How Can I Return The Value?

Tags: javascript, api, web

I'm using The Movie Database API. And the problem that i can't solve is returning "keys" variable when i call the function with Movie's id.I'm new on JavaScript that's why i can't solve this. Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

```
const APIURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=[MY API KEY HERE]&page-1";     
getMovies(APIURL)
async function getMovies(url)
{
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const respData = await resp.json();
    showMovies(respData.results)
}
        async function getTrailer(id)
    {
         const resp = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/videos?api_key=[MY API KEY HERE]&language=en-US`);
         const respDataa = await resp.json();
         let results = respDataa.results;
         let keys = results[0].key;
         return keys;
    }
    
    
    function showMovies(movies){
      movies.forEach(movie => {
           const modals = document.createElement('div');
         modals.classList.add('modal');
         modals.innerHTML = `  <a target="_blank" href ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${getTrailer(movie.id)}">Watch Trailer</a>`

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to await or.then the return (it’s a Promise).

```
function showMovies(movies) {
      // make the forEach callback async
      movies.forEach(async (movie) => {
        console.log(getTrailer(movie.id)) // Promise {<pending>}
    
        const trailer = await getTrailer(movie.id);
        console.log({ trailer });
    
        const modals = document.createElement("div");
        modals.classList.add("modal");
        modals.innerHTML = `  <a target="_blank" href ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${trailer}">Watch Trailer</a>`;
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Async functions return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in JavaScript.
Simply add `return keys` at the end of your function.

Then you can do:

```
getTrailer(528085).then(data => {
 // do something with the data
})
```

You can also handle errors:

```
getTrailer(528085)
  .then(data => {
    // do something with the data
   })
  .catch(err => {
    /* 
    An error occured. You can use err.toString() to convert the error into a string
    */
})
```

If you want to get the returned data immediately from an async function(or a promise), put your logic inside an async function, then you can simply do:

```
let keys = await getTrailer(528085)
```

And, here is how to handle errors in async/await:

```
try {
  let keys = await getTrailer(528085)
}
catch(err){
    /* 
    An error occured. You can use err.toString() to convert the error into a string
    */
}
```

By the way, like Desiigner said, don't keep your API keys in the client. Anyone can see your API key. Use a server to return the API response to the client.

Comment: Hey there thank you so much for your response and advices, all of these give me idea but still having the issue. I've tried your way but i couldn't get the exact value that i want. it's returning promise pending.

Comment: I'm having another function to call this function with id but when it calls the getTrailer() function then it's returning promise pending. i see the promise result that's correct but can't get it and use.I tried .then but still the same issue. I'll edit my post the put more details.

Comment: You can try adding "type=module" in the script tag in HTML. Then, you can simply change ${getTrailer(movie.id)} to ${await getTrailer(movie.id)}

Comment: You can also try to make the function showMovies async

Comment: I tried both but both of them didn't work. It's stil returning promise pending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224896/discussion-between-mithat-ercan-and-fastdeveloper).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, always hide your api keys if you're posting your code somewhere (even if it's a private repository, you shouldn't do it).

Secondly, if you want to return multiple keys, you can map the results to extract id from each of them and do a return:

```
async function getTrailer(id)
{
     const resp = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/videos?api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&language=en-US`);
     const respDataa = await resp.json();
     let results = respDataa.results;
     return results.map(({ key }) => key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and your advices. I understood the idea but it gives me the value in array like ['xxxxxxxx']; so is it possible to do like this      return results.map(({ key[0] }) => key);

Comment: And it is returning promise pending, i can't get the result.